# Elasticsearch for spark 3.0

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch

Im getting issues while using spark3.0 for reading elastic.
My elasticsearch version 7.6.0
I used elastic jar of the same version.
Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). There is no question and few information about your problem. What have you tried so far? If there is some code that fails, post it here.

Comment: Any specific issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spark 3.0.0 relies on Scala 2.12, which is not yet supported by Elasticsearch-hadoop. This and a few further issues prevent us from using Spark 3.0.0 together with Elasticsearch. If you want to compile it yourself, there is a pull-request on elasticsearch-hadoop (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/pull/1308) which should at least allow using scala 2.12. Not sure if it will fix the other issues as well.

Comment: Any updates on the status of Elasticsearch-hadoop supporting Spark 3.0.n and Scala 2.12?

Comment: In the meantime things have changed, the most recent elasticsearch-hadoop version is compatible with Spark 3.1.2 (in our case)

Answer (score 4):

It's officially released for spark 3.0

Enhancements:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/7.12/eshadoop-7.12.0.html

Maven Repository:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-spark-30_2.12/7.12.0

Answer (score 2):

It is not official for now, but you can compile the dependency on
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch, the steps are

1. git clone https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch.git
2. cd elasticsearch-hadoop/
3. vim ~/.bashrc
4. export JAVA8_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
5. source  ~/.bashrc
6. ./gradlew elasticsearch-spark-30:distribution --console=plain

and finally you can find .jar package in folder: "elasticsearch-hadoop\spark\sql-30\build\distributions", elasticsearch-spark-30_2.12-8.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar is the es packages

Comment: and your scala version should be 2.12.x, mine is 2.12.10

Comment: do you have to install scala 2.12 on your local machine?

Comment: @enneppi scala is for the program, not necessary for compiling the dependency. And on my local machine is 2.11.12.  :)